# Why does Google lighthouse see jquery ui vulnerability on my website even though i am no longer using jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, lighthouse

I used to use jquery ui on my website [www.iusefaith.com](http://www.iusefaith.com) but have stopped yet Google lighthouse still sees Jquery Ui on my website. Here is [a link](https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/viewer/?psiurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iusefaith.com%2Findex-en&strategy=mobile&category=performance&category=accessibility&category=best-practices&category=seo&category=pwa&utm_source=lh-chrome-ext#best-practices) to the lighthouse report. Lighthouse says I have jquery ui meanwhile i have removed it.

Why does Google lighthouse see jquery ui vulnerability on my website even though i am no longer using jquery ui ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 69 of: https://res.cloudinary.com/iusefaith/raw/upload/v1606174446/iusefaith_general_jquery_scripts_light_compressed.js

A few hundred characters along (after what looks like Modernizr) I see:

`(function(e,t){function i(t,i){var a,n,r,o=t.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"area"===o?(a=t.parentNode,n=a.name,t.href&&n&&"map"`

compare it to [jQuery-ui 1.10.3](https://gist.github.com/DavidBuell/8427323)

`(function(t,e){function i(e,i){var n,o,a,r=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"area"===r?(n=e.parentNode,o=n.name,e.href&&o&&"map"`

It looks like jQuery-ui from the first few characters there. You need to clear any cache plugins you have and ensure whatever builds the file I linked above doesn't include jQuery-ui anymore.

Comment: Thanks But even though they look at like they are not the same thing. You can see it from the rest of the code. Does it means that I HAVE to delete that portion ?

Comment: Have a look at https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery-ui?lh=1.10.3&utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=ref&utm_campaign=audit - I think it is [this vulnerability](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery-ui:20160721) that needs fixing (if it is present). No you don't have to remove it, it is for your information only, the reason for the false positive is the similarity then, [the method used to detect vulnerable libraries is here for your reference](https://github.com/johnmichel/Library-Detector-for-Chrome/blob/master/library/libraries.js).

Comment: Note that this is presenting itself as jQuery-ui, but I am guessing you have some custom flavour of it `e.ui,{version:"1.10.3",` is where it picked up on the version number it seems.